# Include gwt.xml from ProjectA in ProjectB?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gradle

I have two Gradle projects. Both are in a flat structure which means that they lie on the same path hierarchy.

```
 /parent_dir
   /projectA
   /projectA/shared/Shard.gwt.xml
   /projectB
   /projectB/shared/myProject.gwt.xml
```

I want to include `Shard.gwt.xml` in `myProject.gwt.xml`. This can be done with this line:

```
<inherits name='shared.Shared'/>
```

In projectB in have a `settings.gradle``with the following content on the root path:

```
includeFlat "projectA"
```

The `build.gradle`of projectB looks like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile(project(':projectA')) {
    transitive = false
  }
}
```

With this setting I run `gradle build` and got the error:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find 'shared/Shared.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

**How do include Shared.gwt.xml from ProjectA in ProjectB?**

Comment: do you want the file on the compile classpath or in the build output?

Comment: @Casey on the buld output